# What happens if i delete a document and dont delete its subcollections in firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter app that basically acts as a filter app for another app, meaning i can scroll through certain posts and decide whether to delete them from this app so they dont show up on the other main app.

My question is, since Firestore does not support deleting subcollections, what happens if i just delete the document of the post and ignore the remaining subcollections of things like comments? Is it possible that firestore will later assign a random postId with the same as the one previously deleted and end up showing a deleted post's comments and subcollection info? Because it says on firestore that the ancestor document that doesnt exist for a subcollection that does will not show up in queries does that mean that no other post will be created with the same postId?

Basically Is there any harm for not deleting the subcollections, if there is what do you recommend i do about it, manually delete it?

Comment: You can use a firebase function to delete collections

Comment: @jonasxd360 You cannot delete a collection with the Firestore API. You have to remove the documents within the collection and then it will be removed. See the Firestore Documentation [Delete Collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections). However, it can be done with Cloud Functions.

Comment: @Jay Sorry about my unclear wording, I think we are referring to the same solution of using a firebase cloud function to delete all documents within a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible that firestore will later assign a random postId with the same as the one previously deleted

The collisions of ids in this case is incredibly unlikely and you can/should assume they'll be completely unique. So you don't have to be concerned about it because that's why those ids were designed for, to be unique.

This built-in generator for unique ids that is used in Firestore when you call CollectionReference's `add()` methods or CollectionReference's `document()` method without passing any parameters, generates random and highly unpredictable ids, which prevents hitting certain hotspots in the backend infrastructure.

> does that mean that no other post will be created with the same postId?

Yes, not other document will be created with the same id.

> Basically Is there any harm for not deleting the subcollections

There is not. You can do it in two ways, client side my getting all documents within that subcollection and deleting them in smaller chunks or using a function as @jonasxd360 mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Yes sorry for the delayed reply, so i have a question so if there is no chance of the id being reused then why should i bother deleting the subcollections? Would deleting the document itself not suffice then?

Comment: *why should i bother deleting the subcollections?* You should delete the subcollection because of space and because of the fact that if you'll use collection group query, you might get results from a collection that has obsolete documents. *Would deleting the document itself not suffice then?* If you have an app which does not interfere with those limitations than you are free not to delete the subcollections.

Answer (score 4):

You can use firebase functions to delete collections when a document is deleted. In other words, you would code a function that executes every time a document (in your case post) is deleted. Then you would go through your subcollections and delete them in the function.

To delete a collection I use this code (I didn't code this):

```
    /**
 * Delete a collection, in batches of batchSize. Note that this does
 * not recursively delete subcollections of documents in the collection
 */
function deleteCollection (db, collectionRef, batchSize) {
    var query = collectionRef.orderBy('__name__').limit(batchSize)

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject)
    })
  }

  function deleteQueryBatch (db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject) {
    query.get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
            // When there are no documents left, we are done
            if (snapshot.size === 0) {
              return 0
            }

          // Delete documents in a batch
          var batch = db.batch()
          snapshot.docs.forEach(function (doc) {
            batch.delete(doc.ref)
          })

          return batch.commit().then(function () {
            return snapshot.size
          })
        }).then(function (numDeleted) {
          if (numDeleted <= batchSize) {
            resolve()
            return
          }
          else {
          // Recurse on the next process tick, to avoid
          // exploding the stack.
          return process.nextTick(function () {
            deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject)
          })
        }
      })
        .catch(reject)
      }
```